# Sql Server - Verificar existência de campo NÃO funciona se for para evitar select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

sonsiderem o script abaixo..

Ele verifica se existe a tal couno numa tabela, se existir, faz o select dela.
Em seguida, verifica novamente se existe (somente para fims didaticos ;) ) e existindo Dropa a coluna.

Tudo bem até ai.. agora vem o problema..

Temos se alguem executar o script novamente?
Na teoria, o campo nao existe mais, entao não vai executar nem o selec nem tentar novamente o drop certo?

**ERRADO**

Se você executar somente a primeira parte, vai ver que da erro no select dizendo que a coluna nao existe (a verificação nao adiantou de nada)
Agora se vc executar a segunda parte, funciona! ele NÃO tenta executar o drop, uma vez que a coluna nao existe.

Agora ve a questão.. como faço para conseguir rodar este script N vezes sem retornar erro?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = 'TabelaTal'
              AND COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME = 'campoTal') 
begin
   select campoTal from TabelaTal;   
end;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = 'TabelaTal'
              AND COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME = 'campoTal') 
begin
   ALTER TABLE TabelaTal DROP COLUMN campoTal;   
end;
```

Comment: Mude seu `IF` para `IF COL_LENGTH('TabelaTal' , 'campoTal' ) IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score -1):

Talvez você consiga resolver utilizando a função sp_executesql. Como por exemplo no INSERT abaixo:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
   @name VARCHAR(70) = 'San Francisco',
   @sql_stmt NVARCHAR(100) = 'INSERT INTO cities (name) VALUES (@name)'; 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_stmt, N'@name VARCHAR(70)', @name;
END;
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, você pode consultar diretamente nas tabelas de sistema do seu SGDB.
No caso do SQL Server seria assim:

```
if exists(select column_name
          from mis.information_schema.columns
          where table_schema ='NOMEDOSCHEMA'
          and table_name = 'NOMEDATABELA'
          and column_name = 'NOMEDACOLUNA')
begin
   [SEU SELECT AQUI]
end
```

Abraços

**Rauly Ambrosio**